# Show Edit text on spinner item selected

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` in my class with certain items. I have to display an `EditText` whose visibility I have set to "Invisible". I need to show this `EditText` when "Others" item is selected in the spinner.

Here is my code:-

```
Activity class:-




         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    setContentView(R.layout.maintenance);

                    ETServiceStation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETServiceStation);
                    ETServiceType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETServiceType);
                    ETServiceCost= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETServiceCost);

                    spinServiceType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinServiceType);
                    btnMaintenenceSave= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnMaintenenceSave);
                    btnMaintenanceClear = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnMaintenenceClear);

                    spinServiceType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

                    btnMaintenanceClear.setOnClickListener(this);
                    btnMaintenenceSave.setOnClickListener(this);

                ArrayAdapter<String> serviceTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.array.service_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                serviceTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinServiceType.setAdapter(serviceTypeAdapter);


                }



    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int servicePos, long id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinnerServiceType = spinServiceType.getItemAtPosition(servicePos).toString();


        if(spinnerServiceType.matches("Others"))
        {
            ETServiceType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETServiceType);
            ETServiceType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinnerServiceType = ETServiceType.getText().toString();    
        }
        serviceType = spinnerServiceType;
    }
        }



    Resource:-

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
            <string-array name="service_type_array">
                <item>Full Service</item>
                <item value="serviceother">Other</item>

            </string-array>
        </resources>




     maintenance.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:padding="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maintenance"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25sp" 
                android:textColor="@color/SteelBlue"
                android:typeface="sans"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtServiceStation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Service station name:" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ETServiceStation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtServiceType"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Service type: "/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinServiceType"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ETServiceType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtServiceCost"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Servicing expence:" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ETServiceCost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10" />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <ImageButton
                                         android:id="@+id/btnMaintenenceSave"
                                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                         android:background="@color/white"
                                         android:src="@drawable/fuelbtnsaveclick" />

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/btnMaintenenceClear"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                    android:background="@color/white"
                                    android:src="@drawable/fuelbtnclearclick" />

                    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        Database:
        public long createMainEntry(MaintenanceExpense me)
    {
        ContentValues mcv = new ContentValues();
        mcv.put(KEY_SERVICE_STATION,me.getServiceStation());
        mcv.put(KEY_SERVICE_TYPE,me.getServiceType());
        mcv.put(KEY_SERVICE_COST,me.getServiceCost());
        return otherInfoDatabase.insert(MAINTENANCE_DATABASE_TABLE, null, mcv);
    }
```

I have to display the ETServiceType when "Others" item is clicked.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `editextObject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` should work in your case. Add it inside a condition where value of selected item is `Others`.

Comment: @ShashankKadne umm.. thanks for replying, but I am actually confused on how to do the above code on selecting that particular item.

Comment: `spinServiceType.getSelectedItem().toString();` should give you the text which you can compare against "Others". Or I guess `spinnerServiceType` value too can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            spinnerServiceType = spinServiceType.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //if spinnerServiceType 's value is other
//then set visibility of textview visible put text watcher on it so u can get text when user finished ..if u dont want then u can use simple getText then change its visibility
//As u are setting your array value from resource you cant update it programmatically
//so first of all u have to take its array items in list . so u can update this list after user enter the value in edit text


        }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{    
     if(spinServiceType.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnorecase("Others")
    {
        editextObject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: i had another doubt..I get the edit text alright, but when I enter the text and save it in the database the value doesn't get stored, whereas if i select any value from the spinner(except "Others" ) the value gets stored properly

Comment: @Pooja Gaonkar: Which value do you want to store into database EditText value or Spinner Value?

Comment: If I select "Others" edit text gets displayed, so whatever I enter in the edit text that needs to get saved or else any other value from spinner that is selected that needs to be saved.

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar:Then post your insert query code with how you get insert query parameter code.

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar: You did not post insert query code, but I think you should declare mySpareType String globally and declare it static.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34233/discussion-between-samadhan-medge-and-pooja-gaonkar)